# move_uploaded_file function returns syntax error expecting a closing bracket

Tags: php

I'm probably missing something really basic, but I'm on this apparently simple issue for an hour and still can't figure out what's the problem.
I need to use the function move_uploaded_file to move a file uploaded from a form into a specific folder and I'm getting the following syntax error

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$store_path", expecting ")" in /volume1/web/test/resources_actions.php on line 15*

This is the whole page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
<?php
    include "conn.php";
    $name = $_POST['resource_name'];
    $description = $_POST['resource_description'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $store_path = "files/resources/" . $type . "/";
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$store_path/$filename");
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I've tested:

- different combinations to indicate the file destination (path+filename in a single variable, "$store_path/$filename" as showed in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), but what I get is just a different syntax error (*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected double-quote mark, expecting ")"*))
- $_FILES array is not empty.
- the "rename" function using the same variables and it works perfectly

  rename($tmp_name, $store_path . $filename);
- removing the move_uploaded_file(...) line clean any error
- replace all the double quotes with single quotes and viceversa

Why it's expecting a ")" if this function requires 2 parameters?
The line that throw the error is the move_uploaded_file line.
I'm using PHP 8.0 and I have full access to the folders.

EDIT : I cleaned the code from everything not necessary and posted it in the question.

Comment: I think the error might be before this - would be handy to see line 31 and other code

Comment: If you get exactly the same error message even when using another variable, then obviously that line is not the one throwing the error. What is in line 31 exactly?

Comment: I've added the full code and the line that throw the error is the move_uploaded_file line.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $store_path . "/" . $filename)` - missing semi-colon

Comment: semicolon addedd on that line, but unfortunately still the same error

Comment: What are the contents of the two variables $store_path and $filename?

Comment: Sometimes when you get a syntax error, and you don’t have a good IDE to point out the problem, it is easier to just start deleting lines until you get down to the bare minimum of code that still has the problem.

Comment: @AndrewHardiman the contents are "/files/resources/config/" and "a.txt"

Comment: Not sure you have a valid files path? The result of your string concatenation is "/files/resources/config//a.txt"? You have a double forward slash?

Comment: The updated code did not showing **line 31**. There are just 19 lines. The error tells about that line, it means your code syntax is incorrect between line 31 and before. Show us really full code OR enter one empty line before `move_uploaded_file()` to see if error telling different line or not.

Comment: I've posted the whole page, cleaned from everything unnecessary.

Comment: Just in case: what happens if you just remove the line `move_uploaded_file(...)` ? No error I guess, but just to be sure

Comment: @ZRep: I just read your last comment: "cleaned from everything unnecessary"... Actually, there are still many unnecessary stuffs

Comment: @yolenoyer thanks for the advice, I've done some additional cleaning on the code and yes, if I remove the move_uploaded_file(...) line, I get no errors

Answer (score 0):

So, after an afternoon of tests, what I've done is to try the move_uploaded_file with a single parameter, as the PHP error was basically asking since it was expecting a closing braket after the first parameter

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Once done, I've correctly received the error
*move_uploaded_file() expects exactly 2 arguments, 1 given*
I've then tried again using the correct variables

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $store_path . $filename);
```

and it worked.

Don't ask me why, because I've no idea :) but at least if somebody else get stuck on this error, it's now documented.